# Pass a single parameter to WebApi controller using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to pass a single parameter (string value) to webapi controller but, it is not working. The parameter value is reaching the controller as 'null'. Here is my WebApi config,

```
public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
               name: "DefaultApi",
               routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
           );

        }
    }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetDataView(string request)
        { 
            try
            {
                var result = DB.GetDataView(request);

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {            
                //todo: log exception   
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

AJAX

```
var serverName = 'ds100';
 $.ajax({
        url: 'api/ServerInfo/GetDataView',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: serverName,
        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
```

Am I missing anything? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you can try this `data: {request: serverName}` at your ajax method

Comment: You get a an error: `Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue seems to be on you ajax parameters the `data` parameter receives an object (json) that holds a property for each of the values you are passing in the request, I think you should use

```
 var serverName = 'ds100';
 $.ajax({
    url: 'api/ServerInfo/GetDataView',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {request: serverName} ,
    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

    }
```

and that should do it

Comment: This worked for me but using type:GET. I am still finding out why type:POST is not working. Code is exactly the same except POST

Comment: @SachinPakale have tried not setting `dataType: 'json'`? I think that might be the issue, since it's a `GET` request all info should go in the URL and I think `json` implies it goes like that in the `Body` which `GET` request are not allowed to have. Hope this helps